# Why is this date formatted with a different hour value?

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I have three dates in the database. They all represent 5 pm "real user time" meaning that in real life, the event occurring at those timestamps will occur at 5 pm:

- `1600117200000 (09/14/2020 @ 5:00pm (America/Toronto) - 09/14/2020 @ 9:00pm (UTC)`
- `1615240800000 (03/08/2021 @ 5:00pm (America/Toronto) - 03/08/2021 @ 10:00pm (UTC)`
- `1615842000000 (03/15/2021 @ 5:00pm (America/Toronto) - 03/15/2021 @ 9:00pm (UTC)`

When I run the following, the third date is displayed as 4 pm instead of 5 pm. Why?

```
moment(1600117200000).tz('America/Toronto').format('LLL')
-> "September 14, 2020 5:00 PM"

moment(1615240800000).tz('America/Toronto').format('LLL')
-> "March 8, 2021 5:00 PM"

moment(1615842000000).tz('America/Toronto').format('LLL')
-> "March 15, 2021 4:00 PM"
```

I could understand why the middle date (`1615240800000`) would display an invalid hour since it's in different daylight saving time than I am currently, but the third (`1615842000000`) is in the same daylight saving time as when I execute the code.

Thanks!

Comment: In short you are saying that these all date should have 5pm - regardless of daylight saving ?

Comment: Yes. Well, if March 8 was showing as 4 pm (or 6pm?) I could maybe understand. But March 15 is in the same daylight saving time as September 14. Since they are both 9pm UTC, why is one displaying as 5pm and the other 4pm?

Comment: Can you show me the CDN script for moment timezome you are using  OR are you using an npm package ?

Comment: I was using an old version of the lib. I upgraded it (along with the timezone database) and everything is now fine. :tada:

Comment: thats what i thought - because i could not find any issue. happy to hear all is working

Answer (score 0):

:facepalm: I had an old version of moment-timezone and since the 2021 timezone updates did not exist, it was just displaying an invalid hour. I updated the lib (and database) and everything is fine.